# GEKKO (Python) giving incorrect solution

Tags: python-3.x, gekko

Consider the following GEKKO code:

```html
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Build model

#initialize GEKKO model
m = GEKKO()
m.options.solver = 1

# Seed
np.random.seed(0)

max_r = 5
min_r = 2

b = 2
b_r = {}

for i in range(b):
    b_r[i] = np.random.randint(low=min_r,high=max_r)


u = 2

br = np.random.random((b,u))

lv = m.Array(m.Var,(b, u),lb=0,ub=1, integer=True)

av = {}
for i in range(b):
    av[i] = m.Array(m.Var,(b_r[i], u),lb=0,ub=1, integer=True)


## Constraints
    
for i in range(u):
    lv_sum = m.Const(value=0, name='Link Sum ' + str(i))
    for j in range(b):
        lv_sum += lv[j][i]
    m.Equation(lv_sum <= 1)


for i in range(b):
    for j in range(b_r[i]):
        av_sum = m.Const(value=0, name='Alloc Sum ' + str((i,j)))
        for k in range(u):
            av_sum += av[i][j][k]
        m.Equation(av_sum <= 1)


# Objective function
obj_u = m.Const(value=0, name='Final Objective')
for i in range(u):
    obj_b = m.Const(value=0, name='Objective '+str(i))
    for j in range(b):
        for k in range(b_r[j]):
            obj_b += lv[j][i]*av[j][k][i]*br[j][i]
    obj_u += m.log(1+obj_b)



# Maximize/Minimize objective
m.Maximize(obj_u)

#Set global options
m.options.IMODE = 3 #steady state optimization

# m.options.IMODE = 6 #Dynamic optimization

print(m.path)
#Solve simulation
m.solve()
```

Quite obviously the solution to this piece of code will always be non-negative as we are maximizing `log(1+x)` where `0 <= x`. Yet somehow GEKKO gives the following output:

```html
/tmp/tmpw15jz3zhgk_model0
apm 203.192.204.172_gk_model0 <br><pre> ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.1
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 Warning: there is insufficient data in CSV file 203.192.204.172_gk_model0.csv
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            0
   Constants    :           10
   Variables    :           21
   Intermediates:            0
   Connections  :            0
   Equations    :            8
   Residuals    :            8
 
 Number of state variables:             21
 Number of total equations: -            7
 Number of slack variables: -            7
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :              7
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    7 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj: -2.26E+00 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.460000000952277E-002 sec
 Objective      :   -2.26374259105544     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

The model file is as follows:

```html
Model
Constants
    link_sum_0 = 0
    link_sum_1 = 0
    alloc_sum_0_0_ = 0
    alloc_sum_0_1_ = 0
    alloc_sum_1_0_ = 0
    alloc_sum_1_1_ = 0
    alloc_sum_1_2_ = 0
    final_objective = 0
    objective_0 = 0
    objective_1 = 0
End Constants
Variables
    int_v1 = 0, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v2 = 0, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v3 = 0, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v4 = 0, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v5 = 0, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v6 = 0, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v7 = 0, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v8 = 0, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v9 = 0, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v10 = 0, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v11 = 0, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v12 = 0, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v13 = 0, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v14 = 0, <= 1, >= 0
End Variables
Equations
    ((link_sum_0+int_v1)+int_v3)<=1
    ((link_sum_1+int_v2)+int_v4)<=1
    ((alloc_sum_0_0_+int_v5)+int_v6)<=1
    ((alloc_sum_0_1_+int_v7)+int_v8)<=1
    ((alloc_sum_1_0_+int_v9)+int_v10)<=1
    ((alloc_sum_1_1_+int_v11)+int_v12)<=1
    ((alloc_sum_1_2_+int_v13)+int_v14)<=1
    maximize ((final_objective+log((1+(((((objective_0+((((int_v1)*(int_v5)))*(0.8442657485810173)))+((((int_v1)*(int_v7)))*(0.8442657485810173)))+((((int_v3)*(int_v9)))*(0.8472517387841254)))+((((int_v3)*(int_v11)))*(0.8472517387841254)))+((((int_v3)*(int_v13)))*(0.8472517387841254))))))+log((1+(((((objective_1+((((int_v2)*(int_v6)))*(0.8579456176227568)))+((((int_v2)*(int_v8)))*(0.8579456176227568)))+((((int_v4)*(int_v10)))*(0.6235636967859723)))+((((int_v4)*(int_v12)))*(0.6235636967859723)))+((((int_v4)*(int_v14)))*(0.6235636967859723))))))
End Equations

End Model
```

And the `results.json` file is as follows:

```html
{
  "time" : [0.00],
  "link_sum_0" : [ 0.00              ],
  "link_sum_1" : [ 0.00              ],
  "alloc_sum_0_0_" : [ 0.00              ],
  "alloc_sum_0_1_" : [ 0.00              ],
  "alloc_sum_1_0_" : [ 0.00              ],
  "alloc_sum_1_1_" : [ 0.00              ],
  "alloc_sum_1_2_" : [ 0.00              ],
  "final_objective" : [ 0.00              ],
  "objective_0" : [ 0.00              ],
  "objective_1" : [ 0.00              ],
  "int_v1" : [ 0.00              ],
  "int_v2" : [   1.0000000000E+00],
  "int_v3" : [   1.0000000000E+00],
  "int_v4" : [ 0.00              ],
  "int_v5" : [ 0.00              ],
  "int_v6" : [   1.0000000000E+00],
  "int_v7" : [ 0.00              ],
  "int_v8" : [   1.0000000000E+00],
  "int_v9" : [   1.0000000000E+00],
  "int_v10" : [ 0.00              ],
  "int_v11" : [   1.0000000000E+00],
  "int_v12" : [ 0.00              ],
  "int_v13" : [   1.0000000000E+00],
  "int_v14" : [ 0.00              ],
  "slk_1" : [ 0.00              ],
  "slk_2" : [ 0.00              ],
  "slk_3" : [ 0.00              ],
  "slk_4" : [ 0.00              ],
  "slk_5" : [ 0.00              ],
  "slk_6" : [ 0.00              ],
  "slk_7" : [ 0.00              ]
}
```

I am confused of the folllowing:

1. Why does the `results.json` not match with what is being displayed in the prompt?
2. More importantly why am I getting an incorrect solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `m.Const()` is a constant declaration, not a constraint. Loops such as the following then redefine the constant:

```py
for i in range(u):
    lv_sum = m.Const(value=0, name='Link Sum ' + str(i))
    for j in range(b):
        lv_sum += lv[j][i]
    m.Equation(lv_sum <= 1)
```

Instead, define `lv_sum` and the constraint this way:

```py
for i in range(u):
    lv_sum = m.Var(value=0, ub=1, name='Link Sum ' + str(i))
    m.Equation(lv_sum = sum(lv[1:b][i]))
```

Use `m.Var()` to define the variable and `m.Equation()` to define the equation or `m.Equations()` to define multiple equations at once. Don't use `+=` because it redefines the gekko variable. Instead of loops, try list comprehensions, matrix operations, and vector summations. Here are [examples](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/tree/master/examples) (see `test_arrays.py`, `test_matrix.py`, `test_summations.py`). Once you fix the problem definition, it should give you a correct problem statement that the solver can then solve.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Implemented the changes but still throwing up the same answer. Isn't it a big issue that the answer is negative when there is no way it is possible? Also a bigger issue is I have defined `obj_u` as my objective which has a value of 0 when printed using `.value` but the displayed result is -2.26. Is the objective printed on the prompt wrong?

Comment: The `+=` doesn't work with Gekko variables. Try redefining your model without them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Indeed writing it down explicitly works. But it is not feasible as I am hoping for a general case. Can you point some resources where I can look to see where such things can be made possible.

Comment: Instead of loops, you could try list comprehensions, matrix operations, and vector summations. Here are examples: https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/tree/master/examples (see `test_arrays.py`, `test_matrix.py`, `test_summations.py`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was able to get it to work. Although I don't know if both are the same problem since the solutions are different (which I think may happen due to different constraints). I'll post a follow up question for that. If you incorporate your comments in your answer I'll mark your answer as accepted.